# Появление кнопки при обнаружении полосы прокрутки (скроллинг)

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

как добавить автоматически кнопку (например up, down) если текст в блоке прокручивается. И убирать если блок без скроллинга(мало текста) Есть разные блоки в  одних много текста(есть прокрутка) в других мало[image: введите сюда описание изображения] (без прокрутки)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.block').each(function() {
  const $block = $(this),
    $blockInner = $block.find('.block_inner'),
    $blockContent = $block.find('.block_content'),
    blockInnerHeight = $block.innerHeight(),
    blockContentHeight = $blockContent.height();
  
  /*
  * Альтернативный вариант проверки наличия скролла:
  * if(blockContentHeight > blockInnerHeight) { ... }
  */
  if($blockInner.prop('scrollHeight') > blockInnerHeight) {
    $block.prepend('<button class="block_scroll-button" data-direction="up">Up</button>');
    $block.append('<button class="block_scroll-button" data-direction="down">Down</button>');
  }
  
  $block.on('click', '.block_scroll-button', function() {
    const $this = $(this),
      direction = $this.data('direction'),
      /*
      * если data-direction === 'up', то скроллим вверх
      * иначе в нашем случае data-direction === 'down',
      * тогда скроллим на разность высот .block_content и .block_inner
      */
      scrollTo = direction === 'up' ? 0 : blockContentHeight - blockInnerHeight;
    $blockInner.stop().animate({ scrollTop: scrollTo }, 200);
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.block_inner {
  /*
  * Задаем максимальную высоту блока,
  * если контент больше в высоту, добавится скролл
  */
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.block_content {
  /*
  * Просто что бы всякие margin контента не отталкивали элементы снаружи
  */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block_inner">
    <div class="block_content">
      <ul class="list">
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="block_inner">
    <div class="block_content">
      <ul class="list">
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="block_inner">
    <div class="block_content">
      <ul class="list">
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
        <li class="list_item">List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```