# Добавление элемента в случае если блок имеет scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Дано:

Блоки с текстом. Количество большое. Размер текста внутри блоков разные. Надо отследить , если блок имеет scroll то должна появиться кнопка "вниз" для скролла на нижнюю часть блока.

```js
function scrollable(element) {
    var vertically_scrollable, horizontally_scrollable;

    var e = $('.overflow');

     if (   e.css('overflow') == 'scroll' 
         || e.css('overflow') == 'auto'
         || e.css('overflowY') == 'scroll'
         || e.css('overflowY') == 'auto'
         || e.css('height') != 'none'
                              
         ) {
          $('.overflow').append('<div class="scroll_bottom">BOTTOM</div>');
         return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
.overflow{
  height:300px;
  width:150px;
  overflow:scroll;
  background: white;
}

.scroll_bottom{

   position:absolute;
   bottom:20px;
   right:20px;
   color:#fff;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overflow">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Появление кнопки при обнаружении полосы прокрутки (скроллинг)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/714665/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Готово, всё намного проще.

```js
function scrollable(element) {
     if ( $('.overflow p').height() > $('.overflow').height()) {
          $('.overflow').append('<div class="scroll_bottom">BOTTOM</div>');
         return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
scrollable();
```

```css
.overflow{
  height:300px;
  width:150px;
  overflow:scroll;
  background: white
  position: relative;
}

.scroll_bottom{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0px;
  top:0;
  left:200px;
   color:black;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overflow">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const bottom = $('.scroll_bottom');
$('.overflow').on('scroll', (e)=> (e.currentTarget.scrollTop) ? bottom.show() : bottom.hide());
```

```css
.overflow{
  height:150px;
  width:600px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.scroll_bottom{

   display: none;
   position:fixed;
   bottom:20px;
   right:20px;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll_bottom"></div>
<div class="overflow">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.overflow').on('scroll', e => $('.scroll_bottom').toggleClass('show', !!e.currentTarget.scrollTop));` Нужно больше мимификации xDD